# iOS: it's not possible to share one photo to WhatsApp

Tags: ios, iphone, evernote, whatsapp.app

Why there is no way to share a photo to WhatsApp or Evernote?
Is this a WhatsApp and Evernote limitation?
Or an iOS limitation?

This is only possible if you give the app access to ALL of your photos. You apparently can't just share one. In Facebook this is possible. In android this is beautiful. Why iOS has to be like this?

Answer (score 3):

> Why there is no way to share a photo to whatsapp or evernote?

There is a way to share a picture to `Evernote` with an Extension which has to be turned on first. `WhatsApp`Devs haven't implementet that yet.

> This is only possible if you give the app access to ALL of your photos. You just want to share one.

Privacy is so constructed in iOS you can get Access to Photos or don't. All or nothing. It's much easier for Users and Developers.

> I just want to share one.

The Trick here for `WhatsApp` is, you can tap long on you Photo and you see a `Copy` mark. Copy the picture in your clipboard and the past it into your WhatsApp Chat, so you have only shared `one Image`

Answer (score 1):

With the Sharing Extensions in iOS8 it's possible to share singe photos with an app. Evernote, Facebook and a lot of other apps are providing an extension for this (which must be enabled first) nowadays, I'm not aware of something similar for WhatsApp though.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, Apps need to ask the user/the system to grant them access to the Photo service.

No app can access only one photo. It's either all or none.

FYI, this is Apple's security policy.